# Slider responsive

Tags: javascript, slider

In the project in which I am inserted I am making a page of a team, which will be represented through a slider.

The initial idea was to try to reproduce what the `slick` library does, with the goals of not having to import the `slick`, `jQuery` and also to develop my javascript skills.

When I enter the site for the first time, the slider is set as desired, the problem is when I rezise the page or change the orientation of the phone / tablet the slider does not respect the behavior defined by the script and I can not quite understand the reason.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/saomartinho/pen/gqRBxM)

any suggestion?

```js
const giveSizeToElementSlider = (members, width) => {
 [].forEach.call(members, member => { member.style.width = `${width}px`; })
}


const pageTeam = async (notResize = true) => {
 window.addEventListener('resize', () => pageTeam(false), false);  // check when the window is resized

 let teamContentWidth = document.querySelector('.team').offsetWidth;
 let slider = document.querySelector('.team__slider');
 let members = document.querySelectorAll('.team__member');

 await giveSizeToElementSlider(members, teamContentWidth);

 let membersLength = members.length;
 let memberSize = teamContentWidth;
 let numberOfClones = (notResize) ? 2 : 0;


 slider.style.width = `${memberSize * (membersLength + numberOfClones)}px`;
 slider.style.left = `-${memberSize}px`;

 let firstMember = members[0];
 let lastMember = members[membersLength - 1];

 if (notResize) {
  let cloneFirst = firstMember.cloneNode(true);
  let cloneLast = lastMember.cloneNode(true);

  slider.appendChild(cloneFirst);
  slider.insertBefore(cloneLast, firstMember);
 }


 let positionXOne = 0;
 let positionXTwo = 0;
 let posInitial;
 let posFinal;
 let index = 0;
 let allowShift = true;
 let threshold = 100;

 const dragStart = (event) => {
  event = event || window.event;
  event.preventDefault();

  posInitial = slider.offsetLeft;

  if (event.type == 'touchstart') {
   positionXOne = event.touches[0].clientX;
   return;
  }

  positionXOne = event.clientX;
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', dragEnd);
  document.onmousemove = dragAction;
 }

 const dragAction = (event) => {
  event = event || window.event;

  let clientX = (event.type == 'touchmove') ? event.touches[0].clientX : event.clientX;

  positionXTwo = positionXOne - clientX;
  positionXOne = clientX;

  slider.style.left = `${slider.offsetLeft - positionXTwo}px`;
 }

 const dragEnd = (event) => {
  posFinal = slider.offsetLeft;
  if (posFinal - posInitial < -threshold) {
   shiftSlide(1, 'drag');
  } else if (posFinal - posInitial > threshold) {
     shiftSlide(-1, 'drag');
  } else {
     slider.style.left = `${posInitial}px`;;
  }

  document.onmouseup = null;
  document.onmousemove = null;
 }

 const shiftSlide = (dir, action) => {
  slider.classList.add('shifting');
  if (allowShift) {
   if (!action) { posInitial = slider.offsetLeft; }
   let left = posInitial - memberSize;

   if (dir == 1) {
    index++;
   } else if (dir == -1) {
    left = posInitial + memberSize;
    index--;
   }

   slider.style.left = `${left}px`;
  };

  allowShift = false;
 }

 const checkIndex = () => {
  slider.classList.remove('shifting');

  if (index == -1) {
   slider.style.left = `${-(membersLength * memberSize)}px`;
   index = membersLength - 1;
  }

  if (index == membersLength) {
   slider.style.left = `${-(1 * memberSize)}px`;
     index = 0;
  }

  allowShift = true;
 }

 slider.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart);

 // Touch events
 slider.addEventListener('touchstart', dragStart);
 slider.addEventListener('touchend', dragEnd);
 slider.addEventListener('touchmove', dragAction);

 // Transition events
 slider.addEventListener('transitionend', checkIndex);
}


pageTeam();
```

```css
.team {
 position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

.team__slider {
  display: flex;
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.team__slider.shifting {
 transition: left .2s ease-out;
}

.team__member {
    position: relative;
    height: 270px;
    cursor: ew-resize;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
}

.member__image {
  display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.member__info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50.5%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.member__job {
 font-size: 1.6em;
 line-height: 1.2em;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.member__name {
 font-size: 3.5em;
 line-height: 1em;
}
.team__icon {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 40px;
}

.team__icon--bar {
 width: 78px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.team__icon--hand {
 left: 48%;
 width: 13px;
 animation: drag 3000ms cubic-bezier(.57,-.04,.58,1) infinite both;
 -webkit-animation: drag 3000ms cubic-bezier(.57,-.04,.58,1) infinite both;
}

@keyframes drag {
 0% {
  transform: translateX(-15px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-15px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-15px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-15px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-15px);
 }
 25% {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
 }
 50% {
  transform: translateX(15px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(15px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(15px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(15px);
  -o-transform: translateX(15px);
 }
 75% {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translateX(-15px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-15px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-15px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-15px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-15px);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="team">
 <div class="team__slider">
  <div class="team__member">
   <img src="https://saopera.sa.gov.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/person-placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="member__image">
   <div class="member__info">
    <div class="member__job">JOB</div>
    <div class="member__name">NAME</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team__member">
   <img src="https://saopera.sa.gov.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/person-placeholder.jpg" class="member__image">
   <div class="member__info">
    <div class="member__job">JOB2</div>
    <div class="member__name">NAME2</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team__member">
   <img src="https://saopera.sa.gov.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/person-placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="member__image">
   <div class="member__info">
    <div class="member__job">JOB3</div>
    <div class="member__name">NAME3</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use window on resize event, to set again your slider library

```
window.onresize = function(event) {


};
```

Comment: the error still exists :( by the way, there is some difference between `window.onresize` and `window.addEventListener ('resize', () => {});` ?